# Multiple usernames globally for different git repositories in the same project folder

Tags: git

I have two repository hubs, something like this:

`gitlab.com/` and `company_internal.example.com/opensource/projects`

On gitlab, I use `gitlab@example.com` with username `Company Name` and on the internal hub, I use `my.name@example.com` with `Mrs. Mai Nhame`

With each project, I'll have a setup something like this in each project's `.git/config`:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = ssh://git@gitlab/foo/bar.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
    name = Company Name
    email = gitlab@example.com

[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://company_internal.example.com/opensource/projects/bar.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
    name = Mrs. Mai Nhame
    email = my.name@example.com
```

However, I have to do this for *every*. *single*. *project*. And it's a lot of projects. Not to mention I have to remember it when creating a new project. Is there a way to globally set a different username/email depending on the git repo remote url?

The closest I've seen is the ability to change based on local directory, but in my scenario, the repos share directories and aren't in separate directories.

Comment: The `user.name` and `user.email` options aren't settable by the remote.  You can at most set them per-repository.  If you want to control which credentials are being used to push, you can do that on a per-remote basis, however.

Comment: Thanks. As shown by my example for the remote repository config, the per-repository route is what I've been doing already. Do you know if there's any kind of trigger that can be hooked into to fire a script each time a new git clone is done, perchance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found the closest solution I could do was the following:

I created the following script:

gclone:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone $1
it remote add upstream $2 $3 $4
```

And I put it in my path. Now, instead of `git clone ssh://company_internal.example.com/opensource/projects/bar.git` and then trying to fiddle with the config later, I do `gclone ssh://company_internal.example.com/opensource/projects/bar.git https:// MrsMaiNhameUsername @gitlab/foo/bar.` . However, this only works with the https based repository urls that support usernaming in the url, and it doesn't help my existing repos (only going forward). But at least its a step in the right direction.

Comment: Just discovered the useful git config value: ```[credential "https://example.com"]
 username = me``` and am going to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not provide a way to set per-user configuration based on the URL.  That's because the `user.name` and `user.email` settings are used when making commits, and Git doesn't know where you'll push those commits, if anywhere, when they're being made.  You could push them to one place, multiple places, or nowhere, and in any event, those decisions would come after the fact.  Note that these options control your personal name (that is, something other humans usually call you) and email address, but do not control usernames for connecting to remote servers or other interaction with remotes.

If you want to configure some settings based on the *location on disk*, you can do so like this:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/checkouts/work/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig.work
[includeIf "gitdir:~/checkouts/personal/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig.personal
```

You can then update those two files to contain the configuration settings, including `user.name` and `user.email`, for any repositories within those directories.

If you want to handle multiple usernames or credentials used to authenticate to remote servers, then the Git FAQ explains how to do that, both [for HTTPS](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingHTTP) and [for SSH](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIusemultipleaccountswiththesamehostingproviderusingSSH).

Comment: Sadly, per the title, basing it on location on disk is specifically one of the criteria I'm avoiding.

Comment: Well, that's the knob that Git has to provide to you.  Otherwise, the answer is that what you want to do isn't possible.